# Group By with nHibernate 2.2

Tags: c#, nhibernate-2

Please help me with the following question:

I am working with nHibernate 2.2, VS 2008 and MySQL Db.

**I have a working sql script:**

```
select s.name, count(o.id) from orders o

inner join writers w

    on o.assigned_to = w.id

inner join sites s

    on s.id = w.site_id

where o.date between '2014-09-22 00:00:00' and '2014-09-29 00:00:00'

group by s.name
```

**I am trying to implement it with nHibernate 2.2:**

```
var collection = NHibernateManager.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Writers.Domain.Order), () => orderAlias)
                .CreateAlias(() => orderAlias.AssignedWriter, () => writerAlias, JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .CreateAlias(() => writerAlias.Site, () => siteAlias, JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .Add(() => writerAlias.RegDate > period.From)
                .Add(() => writerAlias.RegDate < period.To)
                .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty(ReflectionHelper.GetMemberName((Site s) => s.Name)))
                    .Add(Projections.Count(ReflectionHelper.GetMemberName((Writers.Domain.Order o) => o.OrderId)), "OrderId")
                ).List();
```

**But I am always getting the following error:**

> Could not resolve property: Name of Writers.Domain.Order.

[image]

Please, help with solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is stating that the `Writers.Domain.Order` object does not have a property called `Name`. Does your `Writers.Domain.Order` object have a `Name` property on it? Does your `orders` table in your database have a `Name` column? If either of those is missing you might get an error like this.

Comment: Of course, the object Order does not have any "Name" property. But I am grouping by "Name" property of Site entety. And the Site object does have this property. I see that I can use only Order's properties in projection. But how to be if I need to use properties of other domain objects like Site in my example?